# What is the 0 indicate at end of the function in this code?

Tags: javascript

What is the 0 define at the end of each function in this code?
Why this code set 0s at the end of the function?

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  model.dragging = getCircleForPosition(e.pageX, e.pageY);
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  model.dragging = undefined;
}, 0);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (model.dragging) {
    model.dragging.x = e.pageX;
    model.dragging.y = e.pageY;
    redraw();
  }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Whatever it is, it's not [within the defined usage of `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - the 3rd argument should be a Boolean or an object, not 0. I'd ask whoever wrote that to fix it (or to explain what they're doing, if there happens to be a legitimate purpose)

Comment: `0` is a falsey value in JS. So its evaluated as `addEventListener(..., ..., false)`

Comment: It's exactly the same as not defining the third parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addEventListener you can basically pass three arguments event, callback and the third one is optional which takes a boolean true for enabling event capturing and false for enabling event bubbling. Here 0 will considered as false hence it will enable event bubbling on the events.

Answer (score 1):

The 0 basically indicates a false value.
According to docs

> true - The event handler is executed in the capturing phase
>
> false-
> Default. The event handler is executed in the bubbling phase

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of the `addEventListner` function can ether be the `options` object or a boolean value indicating the capturing mode.

> useCapture (Optional) -- 
>   A Boolean indicating whether events of this type
>   will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched
>   to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events that are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener
>   designated to use capture. Event bubbling and capturing are two ways
>   of propagating events which occur in an element that is nested within
>   another element, when both elements have registered a handle for that
>   event. The event propagation mode determines the order in which
>   elements receive the event. See DOM Level 3 Events and JavaScript
>   Event order for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture
>   defaults to false.

If your 0 value is interprets in a boolean context, it is to tell the even listener to not use the capture - which is the default.